# Set this CSS rule using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using this css:

```
#hideSidebarText:hover > #hideSidebarArrows {
background-position: -282px -51px;
}
```

how can I change the "background-position" property using JQuery? I tryied the following code but obviously didn't worked:

```
$('#hideSidebarText:hover > #hideSidebarArrows').css('background-position', '-282px -31px');
```

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for this?

Comment: `:hover` pseudo selector doesn't work in javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pseudo-selector, it doesn't select an actual element so jQuery can't work with it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I thought that it was the best solution, but I didn't know that it isn't supported... is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @Taze T. Schnitzel: It being a pseudo-class (or "pseudo-selector") doesn't really have anything to do with it not working in jQuery...

Comment: Yes it does. The selector syntax in jQuery is for finding actual DOM objects, but pseudo-elements are not real elements so they cannot be "found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've overqualified the element your targeting(also as @vega pointed out hover doesn't work), if you want to apply that CSS to the element with the ID hideSidebarArrows do it directly instead of searching for it with about element.

```
$("#hideSidebarArrows").hover(
    function () {
       $(this).css('background-position', '-282px -31px');
});
```